# .NET application and IIS exit with error -1 without stopping the debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, debugging, iis, crash

I have a VirtualBox machine with Windows 10. There is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 installed as IDE for the development of a .NET/ASP.NET application.

I ran the machine about one years ago and I was able to successfully build and debug the application.
Few days ago I launched again the VM, of course Windows had to apply its mandatory updates.

Now when I debug the application, it immediately exit with error -1 after loading the libraries:

```
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\MYPEngine.exe' completato. Simboli caricati.
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll' completato. Modulo compilato senza simboli.
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Autofac.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Owin.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Owin.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Autofac.Integration.SignalR.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\Autofac.Integration.Owin.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\System.Web.Cors.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\NLog.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\EasyModbus.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CIPCompolet\1.7.1.0__f3505d5782c23c5d\CIPCompolet.dll' completato. Modulo compilato senza simboli.
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MYP\engine\MYP\MYPEngine\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.resources.dll' completato. Modulo compilato senza simboli.
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' completato. 
'MYPEngine.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MYPEngine.exe): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133355287811706310): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' completato. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): caricamento di 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' completato. Modulo compilato senza simboli.

Il programma '[11672] MYPEngine.exe' è terminato con il codice -1 (0xffffffff).
Il programma '[7060] iisexpress.exe' è terminato con il codice -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I'm building in debug mode and started a debug session. But the debugger does not halt anywhere. The application just crashes.
I also enabled *all* the exceptions with the hope to catch what prevents the application to run.

What tools or approaches can I use to find out the reason of such a behavior?

The application is quite large and I'm not sure which part should I share.
And please remember, all worked fine during the previous runs of the VM.

Comment: You can try to check whether there are related error messages in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @samwu should I look for 'iisexpress.exe', shouldn't I? Otherwise, if the root cause was my application I should be able to debug inside the IDE, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it should be a compatibility problem after the update.